# grafana - alerting via slack, images aren't showing up

Tags: grafana

I'm trying to get graphs to show up in my Grafana v4 alerts in Slack.

When i use the test notification button, I get a pretty graph.

[image: Alerting via Test Notification]

However, when my alerts go through no graph :(

[image]

Here are my logs when an alert is triggered:

```
t=2016-12-07T10:43:01+0000 lvl=info msg="New state change" logger=alerting.resultHandler alertId=1 newState=ok prev state=alerting
t=2016-12-07T10:43:01+0000 lvl=info msg="Sending notifications for" logger=alerting.notifier ruleId=1 sent count=1
t=2016-12-07T10:43:01+0000 lvl=info msg=Rendering logger=png-renderer path="dashboard-solo/db/sample-alerts?&panelId=1"
t=2016-12-07T10:43:07+0000 lvl=info msg=uploaded logger=alerting.notifier url=
t=2016-12-07T10:43:07+0000 lvl=info msg="Sending notification" logger=alerting.notifier type=slack id=1 isDefault=true
t=2016-12-07T10:43:07+0000 lvl=info msg="Executing slack notification" logger=alerting.notifier.slack ruleId=1 notification="Slack #skyline"

t=2016-12-07T11:05:17+0000 lvl=info msg="Initializing Alerting" logger=alerting.engine
t=2016-12-07T11:23:35+0000 lvl=info msg="New state change" logger=alerting.resultHandler alertId=2 newState=alerting prev state=pending
t=2016-12-07T11:23:35+0000 lvl=info msg="Sending notifications for" logger=alerting.notifier ruleId=2 sent count=1
t=2016-12-07T11:23:44+0000 lvl=info msg=uploaded logger=alerting.notifier url=
t=2016-12-07T11:23:44+0000 lvl=info msg="Sending notification" logger=alerting.notifier type=slack id=1 isDefault=true
t=2016-12-07T11:23:44+0000 lvl=info msg="Executing slack notification" logger=alerting.notifier.slack ruleId=2 notification="Slack #skyline"
```

I attempted to configure the s3 buckets which I may have done incorrectly, but i'm surprised to not see any error messages in the logs if that was the case.  Some of the log messages indicating a rendering action and others dont.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was i forgot to comment out the

```
# provider = s3

provider = s3
```

Comment: where did you modified this? in a slack template or in alertmanager configuration?